# (Updated - new issue) - Matlab - Displaying bar graph in GUIDE GUI Issue

Tags: matlab, user-interface, graph, matlab-guide

This is the bar graph that I want to display on the GUIDE GUI. I put this code into the OpeningFcn function of the GUIDE GUI, and what essentially happens is that the actual box section dedicated to the graph (its tagged "axes1") appears in the GUI window, but then another Figure window appears displaying the bar graph. How would I go about placing this bar graph into the GUIDE GUI in the space dedicated to the box axes1?

I do not need any push button trigger to display it. The graph should appear in its dedicated spot on the GUIDE GUI when the GUI window is open.

**EDIT: This is the graph data I want to display. I was using the previous one as an example so I could learn from it. However, for some reason there is a problem of the below graph appearing twice in the window - it appears once, closes, and then appears again. How would I fix it so it only appears once? All of this is under OpeningFcn and I don't have additional code under CreateFcn.**

```
dbedit = matfile('varDatabase.mat', 'Writable', true);
results_pData = dbedit.pData;
results_uData = dbedit.uData;
results_name = dbedit.name;

% Create data for each set of bars for data from each group 
% i.e. [participant, population].
% Population is defined as the previous user data stored in its full in uData. 
expSingle = [((results_pData(1,2)/7)*100), ((mean(results_uData(:,2))/7)*100)];
expConjugate = [((results_pData(1,3)/7)*100), ((mean(results_uData(:,3))/7)*100)];
ctlSingle = [((results_pData(1,4)/7)*100), ((mean(results_uData(:,4))/7)*100)];
ctlConjugate = [((results_pData(1,5)/7)*100), ((mean(results_uData(:,5))/7)*100)];

% Create a vertical bar chart using the bar function
bar(handles.axes1,1:2, [expSingle' expConjugate' ctlSingle' ctlConjugate'], 1)

% Set the axis limits
axis([0 2.8 0 100])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{results_name,'Population'})

% Add title and axis labels
title('Proportion of Responses for Conjunctive vs. Single Choices')
xlabel('Entity')
ylabel('Proportion of Responses (%)')

% Add a legend
legend('Single Choice, Experimental', 'Conjugative Choice, Experimental',...
'Single Choice, Control', 'Conjugative Choice, Control')
```

Input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of your call to figure right after the creation of your data, which indeed creates a new figure outside of your GUI.

To solve your problem remove that line, and consider adding the actual axes handles in the call to `bar`:

```
bar(handles.axes1,1:12, [measles' mumps' chickenPox'], 1)
```

Therefore your whole code could look like this:

```
%Create data for childhood disease cases
measles = [38556 24472 14556 18060 19549 8122 28541 7880 3283 4135 7953 1884];
mumps = [20178 23536 34561 37395 36072 32237 18597 9408 6005 6268 8963 13882];
chickenPox = [37140 32169 37533 39103 33244 23269 16737 5411 3435 6052 12825 23332];

%Create a vertical bar chart using the bar function 

%// Remove the call to figure.
bar(handles.axes1,1:12, [measles' mumps' chickenPox'], 1)

% Set the axis limits
axis([0 13 0 40000])
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:12)

% Add title and axis labels
title('Childhood diseases by month')
xlabel('Month')
ylabel('Cases (in thousands)')

% Add a legend

legend('Measles', 'Mumps', 'Chicken pox')
```

That should work now

Comment: Now the issue is that the graph appears once, disappears and then appears again (as if 2 windows opened). I have no code under CreateFcn, and all the of the above code is in OpeningFcn. How would I fix that?

Comment: My apologies I should have posted the original code that I had in the beginning. It is now updated and now I have the issue of the graph appearing once, disappearing and then appearing again (as if 2 windows opened). How would I fix it so only 1 appears and is maintained until closed?

Comment: I don't understand does this answer solve the original problem? I don't see how come you would have figures appearing and disappearing with the above code.

Comment: I re-checked and it turns out that it is working. What the problem was that the figure was too small and so the push button underneath it was appearing in a separate screen. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome then glad to help!